# jasmine 2.0 test with a custom matcher fails: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have this function in my source file:

```
function gimmeANumber(){
    var x = 4;
    return x;
}
```

And a spec borrowed from [this tutorial](http://evanhahn.com/how-do-i-jasmine/)

```
describe('Hello world', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        this.addMatchers({
            toBeDivisibleByTwo: function() {
                return (this.actual % 2) === 0;
            }
        });
    });

    it('is divisible by 2', function() {
        expect(gimmeANumber()).toBeDivisibleByTwo();
    });

});
```

This is the error:

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object. (file:///home/n/foo/jasmine/jasmine-2.0.0/dist/spec/HelloWorldSpec.js...)
Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The API for adding custom matchers has changed since 1.3.
You can see the changes [here](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers#writing-new-matchers).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/7W2XB/) is how it works now:

```
function gimmeANumber() {
    var x = 4;
    return x;
}

describe('Hello world', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        jasmine.addMatchers({
            toBeDivisibleByTwo: function () {
                return {
                    compare: function (actual, expected) {
                        return {
                            pass: (actual % 2) === 0
                        };
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    });

    it('is divisible by 2', function () {
        expect(gimmeANumber()).toBeDivisibleByTwo();
        expect(5).not.toBeDivisibleByTwo();
    });

});
```

Comment: Add a 'message' property to the return obj to customize message. Ex. return { pass: typeof actual === 'number', message: actual +' should be a number' };